# While processing files with templating-compiler (for target web.browser)

Tags: javascript, html, css, meteor

As a beginner I have ran simple-todos application in meteor which working fine, Now i have done some little modification in **main.html** as below

```
<head>
  <title>mywebapp</title>
</head>
<style>
  body
  {
    background-image: url("mainimage.jpg");
  }
</style>
<body>
  <h1>Development in progress</h1>
</body>
```

But when i refresh the page the i see below error

> Errors prevented startup:
>
> While processing files with templating-compiler (for target web.browser):
>   client/main.html:1: Expected one of: `<body>`, `<head>`, `<template>`
>
> Your application has errors. Waiting for file change.

I don't have any clue about this error. Can any one tell me what is the issue?

main.css

```
/* CSS declarations go here */
<style>
  body
  {
    background-image: url("mainimage.jpg");
  }
</style>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define your styles in a css file, not as a `<style>` block in your html. You don't even need to import the css file, Meteor will include it automatically.

Comment: Thanks for answer. But now i am seeing this error 'app/client/main.css:8:1: missing '{''.

Comment: Then you have a missing `{` in your css file! Your editor should help you find unbalanced delimiters...

Comment: CSS file seems fine to me. See edited question in which i pasted main.css file.

Comment: css file doesn't need a `<style>` declaration, that's html.

Answer (score 1):

For me, the issue was in "build" folder when taking the build, so I created new folder outside of app folder as "outsidefolder".

```
meteor build ../outsidefolder --server=https://marketing-app-wd.herokuapp
```